# MySQL Select query on a saved View results in error 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, select, view

I am able to run the below query and it works fine showing the results:

```
SELECT
p.*,
IFNULL(t.tip,0) as tip
FROM
`view_postmeta1` p LEFT OUTER JOIN `view_tip` t on p.post_id = t.order_id;
```

When I create a view, the view gets created successfully:

```
CREATE VIEW `view_order` AS (
    SELECT
    p.*,
    IFNULL(t.tip,0) as tip
FROM
    `view_postmeta1` p LEFT OUTER JOIN `view_tip` t on p.post_id = t.order_id);
```

But when I query the view, I get ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

```
SELECT * FROM view_order;
```

My question is how to save the working select query to a view and then viewing the results of the saved view? I am using MySQL 5.6.16. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks,

Comment: Is this taking a long time to run?

Comment: It should work. There is nothing wrong. It may take much time.

Comment: Are `view_postmeta1` and  `view_tip` also views?

Comment: It does not take a long time to run. It just quits. view_postmeta1 and view_tip are also views.

Comment: Maybe you should also post the definition of the two views. Not sure, what I expect to find there, but who knows..

Comment: The same queries work with 1and1 MySQL 5.5 but doesn't work on my xampp MySQL 5.6. Appears to be some sort of of compatibility issues.